# Keras....unsupported operand type RNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am following code from a book (Hands on Machine Learning) and I'm running into this error all the code below is everything I have.

```
shakespeare_url = "https://homl.info/shakespeare" # shortcut URL
filepath = keras.utils.get_file("shakespeare.txt", shakespeare_url)

with open(filepath) as f:
    shakespeare_text = f.read()

tokenizer = keras.preprocessing.text.Tokenizer(char_level=True)

tokenizer.fit_on_texts([shakespeare_text])

max_id = len(tokenizer.word_index) # number of distinct characters
dataset_size = tokenizer.document_count # total number of characters
[encoded] = np.array(tokenizer.texts_to_sequences([shakespeare_text])) - 1
train_size = dataset_size * 90 // 100
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(encoded[:train_size])

n_steps = 100
window_length = n_steps + 1 # target = input shifted 1 character ahead
dataset = dataset.window(window_length, shift=1, drop_remainder=True)

dataset = dataset.flat_map(lambda window: window.batch(window_length))

batch_size = 32
dataset = dataset.shuffle(10000).batch(batch_size)
dataset = dataset.map(lambda windows: (windows[:, :-1], windows[:, 1:]))

dataset = dataset.map(
    lambda X_batch, Y_batch: (tf.one_hot(X_batch, depth=max_id), Y_batch))
dataset = dataset.prefetch(1)

model = keras.models.Sequential([
    keras.layers.GRU(128, return_sequences=True, input_shape=[None, max_id], dropout=0.2, 
                     recurrent_dropout=0.2),
    keras.layers.GRU(128, return_sequences=True, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2),
    keras.layers.TimeDistributed(keras.layers.Dense(max_id, activation="softmax"))
])
model.compile(loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="adam")
history = model.fit(dataset, epochs=20)
```

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>   ----> 1 history = model.fit(dataset, epochs=20)
>
> ~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py
>   in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks,
>   validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight,
>   sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps,
>   validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing,
>   **kwargs)
>       817         max_queue_size=max_queue_size,
>       818         workers=workers,
>   --> 819         use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
>       820 
>       821   def evaluate(self,
>
> ~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2.py
>   in fit(self, model, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks,
>   validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight,
>   sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps,
>   validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing,
>   **kwargs)
>       340                 mode=ModeKeys.TRAIN,
>       341                 training_context=training_context,
>   --> 342                 total_epochs=epochs)
>       343             cbks.make_logs(model, epoch_logs, training_result, ModeKeys.TRAIN)
>       344
>
> ~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2.py
>   in run_one_epoch(model, iterator, execution_function, dataset_size,
>   batch_size, strategy, steps_per_epoch, num_samples, mode,
>   training_context, total_epochs)
>       150               '{} batches). You may need to use the repeat() function '
>       151               'when building your dataset.'.format(
>   --> 152                   total_epochs * steps_per_epoch))
>       153         # In either case, break out the loop for training batch.
>       154         # Also note the training_context that data inputs are exhausted, so all
>
> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'NoneType'

Comment: What line raises that error?

Comment: TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-109-300251d1d769> in <module>
----> 1 history = model.fit(dataset, epochs=20)                                                                              This is in my code it flagged here

Comment: Please provide the full traceback in the question with an [edit].